# New google identity service change

Tags: single-sign-on, google-signin

I am using google identity services(https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) for sign in to my web game application.
Initialization completed using below code.

google.accounts.id.initialize({
client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
callback: handleCredentialResponse
});

I would like to invoke google promt popup via  button click, because I can't use the default button in game. We followed the same guidelines to create a new one.
I tried to use

```
google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

,But it work only in the case of active session. Pls help me here
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? While the one answer is generally helpful... I am also slamming face into wall with new google sign in protocol and needing a nice 'original clean' way of doing the google login prompt on a custom button press. Their new system is BS, and doesnt even work right in Safari (which comprises half our user-base).

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to render either the Sign In With Google button, One Tap, or both purely from JavaScript this may help:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script>
    function handleCredentialResponse() {
      console.log('hello, world');
    }
    window.onload = function () {
    
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
      });
      
      // Display the One Tap prompt
      google.accounts.id.prompt();
      
      // Display the Sign In With Google Button
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
        { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' }
      );
    }
    </script>


    <pre>One Tap renders a popup, button requires a div to position it on the page</pre>
    <div id='buttonDiv'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You'd just conditionality call the `id.prompt` or `id.renderButton` methods to control when each is displayed to the user.

If the user has an active session--they are signed into their Google Account the Sign In With Google button will show their name, email, profile pic... it's personalized. If they are not signed into a Google Account the button will simply default to display 'Sign In With Google' or the value of the `data-text` attribute.

FYI, there are several valid reasons the One Tap prompt might not be displayed. You'll want to consider using [`PromptMomentNotification`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en#PromptMomentNotification) to debug and adjust accordingly.

Comment: 'id.prompt' will work in my case, but the problem is there should be an active google session, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Right, this is by design. In order to share a JWT with the user's identity to your app the user must first be signed into their Google account and have granted permission to share their profile. Note that the active session between the Google Account and the user is NOT the same as a session between the user and your app.

Comment: Is there any way to invoke google sign in button functionality manually? As I mentioned earlier, i can't use Google default button.

Comment: @RintoAvarachan there seems to be a [wrapper](https://medium.com/@leonardosalles/a-guide-to-custom-google-sign-in-button-e7b02c2c5e4f) you can add to mimic the sign-in button click. I didn't get it to work because my `renderButton` is giving error.